# Is marriage preferred between the people having mars in 1st house and 2nd houses?

Tags: belief, marriage, astrology, kundali

Is marriage preferred between the people having mars in 1st house and 2nd houses (lagna and moon kuja dosha) or persons should find the horoscope having mars in the same houses?
Is marriage suggested between the manglik and non manglik person when they perform remedies like kumbh vivah?
I read somewhere that the dosha gets cancelled when the person born on Tuesday also it gets cancelled after 28 years, is it true?
Is there any scriptures explaining all these Manglik doshas?

Comment: No remedy can remove a manglik dosha. However people say they have examples of happy marriages between magalik and non-magalik, they are not talking about complete life. The problem is when it really starts affecting a person. At young age, or when the person gets old enough. I am not an astrologer although: https://youtu.be/TtVgiOfeMbU